# Two different ways to optimize ex-ante correlation of a long / short portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, covariance-matrix

Assuming I am making a long/short portfolio of S&P500 stocks and I would like to use the historical correlations to minimize ex-ante portfolio volatility. I can think of two ways of doing this:

First method

1. Calculate covariance matrix based on some look-back period.
2. Use optimizer to find weights that minimize wT @ cov @ w

Second method

1. Gather return data over some look-back period.
2. Use optimizer to find weights which minimize the volatility of the portfolio throughout the lookback period.

They're both using the same look-back period data so would they yield the same results?

Comment: In the second method, the weights are fixed over the entire lookback period, right?

Comment: yes that is correct